# How to compare two hashmaps in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I want to compare two objects that contain hashmaps, the goal is to recover the conflicting properties (the same keys with different values in the two objects). For example:

```
Object1 : {
1234567891001 : 1
1234567891002 : 2
1234567891003 : 8
1234567891004 : 9
}

Object2 : {
1234567891001 : 1
1234567891002 : 2
1234567891003 : 3
1234567891004 : 4
}
```

- Output: List + Message (result list is extracted from object 1)

  1234567891003 : 8
  1234567891004 : 9

The EAN 1234567891003 should be composed of 3 instead of 8
The EAN 1234567891004 should be composed of 4 instead of 9

Comment: can you please explain what does this mean The EAN 1234567891003 should be composed of 3 instead of 8 The EAN 1234567891004 should be composed of 4 instead of 9

Comment: Please show what you have already tried

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is exactly what you're asking for, but it should at least help you along:

```
var result = {};
var conflicts = {};
Object.keys(Object1).forEach((key) => {
  if (Object2.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    conflicts[key] = Object1[key];
    result[key] = Object2[key];
  } else {
    result[key] = Object1[key];
  }
});

console.log("Conflicts", conflicts);
console.log("Result", result);
```

---

**Edit**: OK, so after re-reading your question I realized you actually want two lists: one result list and one conflicts list. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an iterative approach over the keys of `object1` and create a new object with the proerties with the difference value.

```js
var object1 = { 1234567891001: 1, 1234567891002: 2, 1234567891003: 8, 1234567891004: 9 },
    object2 = { 1234567891001: 1, 1234567891002: 2, 1234567891003: 3, 1234567891004: 4 },
    difference = {};

Object.keys(object1).forEach(function (k) {
    if (object1[k] !== object2[k]) {
        difference[k] = object1[k];
    }
});

console.log(difference);
```